# VS Code merge tool missing buttons

Tags: visual-studio-code, merge-conflict-resolution

I am using the merge tool in visual studio code 1.76.2. For most of the conflicts it shows convenient buttons above each side: “accept incoming”, “ accept current“.  But in a handful of them, mostly one-liners, it does not. The only option I get is down below in the merged view, “reset to base“.

In the snapshot shown here, I would really like to use the “incoming“ version of the first displayed merge and the “current“ version of the second. But the buttons are missing. What should I do?  Is this a bug? Is there an update or a bug fix that would help with displaying all the buttons?

Using GitLens 13.4.0, in case it matters.[image]